# What is good practice when deciding where enums and structs should be defined?

Tags: c#

Assuming that the `enum` or `struct` is not nested within a particular class i.e. it belongs to the project namespace, should it be defined in:

- Its own file
- A general-purpose file called `Enums.cs` or `Structs.cs` where all the `enums`/`structs` that belong to the project namespace would be defined
- Somewhere else...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This MSDN article on enum best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229058.aspx) makes no recommendation on where to store enum definitions.

You'll get different recommendations.  Personally, I tend to store enums in the same file as the class they're related to.  I like to keep my file structure the same as my namespace structure, as much as possible, and so if my enums naturally fall into a particular namespace, I'll store the definition in the corresponding file.

My suggestion is, find a scheme that works for you, and stick with it.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I prefer the one type, one file philosophy.  I even go so far as having nested types in separate files with partial classes used to allow the separation.

I mainly do this because I've seen far too much of the opposite.  Single files that contain dozens of classes.  The experience changed me.

Comment: I agree with you, for pretty much everything but enums.  I can't bring myself to create a separate file for five lines of code.  I respect your reasoning, though.

Comment: Don't forget Michael, if it makes it more readable and understable, then it can never hurt to have a little filesystem overhead. :)

Answer (score 6):

For me, one type = one file, unless it's a delegate. I don't need to declare my own delegates very often these days due to `Func` and `Action`, but when I do I find it's useful to have a `Delegates.cs` file.

As for structs - I can only ever remember writing about two of them, aside from for the purposes of testing the evil things that *mutable* structs can do. But I'd stick to one per file there too. Why wouldn't you? Just because they're value types doesn't mean they're naturally shorter or simpler than classes. (Can you imagine if `decimal` and `DateTime` were both in the same source file? Eek!)

EDIT: I've just thought of another case where having multiple structs may be appropriate: interop. In that case I might have Interop.cs or Win32.cs... or possibly a namespace for it and back to one file per type.

Answer (score 2):

I put all of my enums in their own file. However, I also fully xml doccomment all of my types, including enums...so there are probably many more lines of code in my enum files than in most peoples.

I haven't written a struct in many, many years, but I don't consider them to be any less than a class (and again, I fully xml doccomment all of my types, structs included), so they have in the past always had their own file too.

When it comes to delegates, being as they are usually one liners (minus doccomment), I tend to keep them in the same file as whatever more prominent type they support. I don't often write delegates these days, but sometimes I find they still have a use. However, I try to keep any delegates declared at the top of the file, rather than nested or below the main type...makes em easier to spot when you go looking for them.

I think there is also a very simple but practical reason to keep each type in its own file. They are very EASY to spot that way. If you bury your enums and structs inside other types, or keep them within another file, sometimes (and don't assume you, and the people reading your code, always have access to Visual Studio and all of its rich tools) it can be quite difficult to find the type your looking for.